# Task.Run() in async ASP.Net MVC Controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I need your advise on using `Task.Run()` in ASP.NET MVC async controller action. We currently have a time consuming backend SP that takes few minutes to execute when user clicks "Approve". User just need to approve and need not wait until this backend execution completes so we are using `Task.Run` here as seen in the below code.

Earlier this was done by `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` so that it is done in the background. Now, we are migrating this app to ASP.Net MVC 5.0.

We tested this and its all working fine but we need to make sure if this will not create any problems in future. Please advise.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ApprovePayments(int Id)
{
 await (db.PaymentApprove(Id, User == null ? "" : User.Identity.Name));
 Task.Run(() => {
                    DBModel dbReport = new DBModel();
                    dbReport.PaymentReportCreate(Id);
                    dbReport.Dispose();
                });
 SetUnapprovedPaymentsViewBag();
  return View("PendingPayments");    
}
```

Comment: Scott Hanselman did a round-up a few years ago: [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

> We tested this and its all working fine but we need to make sure if this will not create any problems in future.

Yes, it certainly can cause problems because ASP.NET is not aware of your background work.

I describe a [variety of approaches](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) on my blog. The only *reliable* solution is to save the work to persistent storage and have an independent worker processing it. Hangfire is one such solution.

But if you're OK with occasionally losing work, then you can register the background work with `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`.

Under no circumstances should you use `Task.Run` or `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` to kick off background work.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. The old application was working fine with ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem without any issues for the last 5 years. So, we decided to replace it with Task.Run() now. The whole of the background work is fully done by SP so when the SP is initiated it should run and complete successfully though ASP.Net worker process may stopped. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Bala: I don't know what you mean by "SP". If this is a separate process, then that approach may be reliable.

Comment: @Bala: In that case, it should work. With the caveat that you have no way for your web app to know if the SP fails.

Comment: Yes. Thanks Stephen.